# Difference between Income-Expenditure Identity and the Goods Market Equilibrium condition

Tags: macroeconomics, national-accounts

Is there any difference between the Income-Expenditure Identity and the Goods Market Equilibrium condition. Both are $Y=C+I+G+NX$. If it is an identity, why do we solve for the equilibrium output? Shouldn't it always hold? If someone could clarify this it would be very helpful.

Answer (score 2):

The output defined with spending approach: $Y\equiv C+I+G+NX$ is an identity because it holds by definition. By definition output must be equal to sum of spending, investment government spending and net exports. However, this is actually **not** the equilibrium condition.

The equilibrium condition is that goods market demand $Z$ must be equal to output in the equilibrium. Hence the equilibrium condition is that $Z=Y$ (this is really just macro version of saying that demand = supply, since output $Y$ is the supply). This is the equilibrium condition not the identity $Y\equiv C+I+G+NX$. However, *given* that the equilibrium condition is that $Z=Y$ we can from that deduce the following: $Z=Y \implies Z= C+ I + G + NX$ *in equilibrium*.

This might be easier to explain with graph. Consider the following graph from Blanchard et al. Macroeconomics a European Perspective pp 47. In the graph below the demand is the purple line while the identity $Y \equiv C+I+G$ (they omit net exports for simplicity) is the $45°$ line that just definitionally says output is equal to output.

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This is an important question which is usually covered in good undergraduate texts. You are correct in pointing out that the two *appear* to be same. But there is a subtle difference.

The difference comes through the definition of $I$. The Income-Expenditure Identity is an accounting identity in which $I$ is the realized investment expenditure which includes *changes* in inventory.

In the Goods market equilibrium, $I$ (in some good texts denoted by $I_p$) is the investment demand or planned investment expenditure (hence the subscript $p$). This is a function of real interest rate $r$ which gives you IS curve with equilibrium a function of income $Y$ and interest rate $r$. Clearly, this does not include the changes in inventory (at least not the unplanned ones).

You can see [this](https://faculty.washington.edu/danby/bls324/macro/bop/1-3new.html) link for some more details and examples.